# FancyBox Will Not Play youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I am having difficulty getting the Jquery fancybox plugin to play youtube videos.  I've gone through a few of the solutions others have posted on this site, but I am still missing something, somewhere, but I can't see it.  New to the world of coding and such.

Okay.  Here I've made a quick test page and grabbed a random youtube video.  Here is how my page code looks:

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancyapps-fancyBox-        18d1712/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancyapps-fancyBox-18d1712/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancyapps-fancyBox-18d1712/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.videos').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
        media : {}
        }
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>


<body>
<ul class="list">
<li><a class="videos" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hS5CfP8n_js">Youtube</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the answer laid out [here](http://webdesignandsuch.com/fancybox-youtube-videos/)?

```
$(".videos").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'padding'       : 0,
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'title'         : this.title,
        'width'         : 640,
        'height'        : 385,
        'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type'          : 'swf',
        'swf'           : {
        'wmode'             : 'transparent',
        'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

If your link goes directly to the embedded version already you could change the href to simply be this.href or just remove.